# Is it possible to automatically hide all the range of (a ~ MAX)th children element in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know it's very easy to do it with JavaScript. For example, if I want to hide all children after 50th, I just need to do:

```
$("#container").find('div').each(function(){
  if ($(this).index() > 50) $(this).hide();
})
```

But is it possible to do it with **pure CSS**?

Note:

- The total children number is not a fixed one. It may change (by other JavaScript codes
- I only need to support Chrome so no need to consider other browsers
- I don't have access to the HTML DOM itself (because I am building a Chrome Extension)

Update:

- Sorry that I want to hide from `a to All the next` (the last one) children. I have edited my question. It's NOT from `a~b`.
- div are the only children. There are NO other children in this container.

Comment: are the `div` the only children of the `#container` ?

Comment: CSS Quantity Queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.container div:nth-child(n+51) {
    display:none;
}`

n is the cycle number, 51 is the offset so will start on the 51st item, then repeat every 1 item.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use the `~` selector in order to hide all the element after a particular one:

```
.container div:nth-child(51) ~ * {
   display:none;
}
```

Here is an example:

```css
.container div:nth-child(5) ~ * {
  display: none;
}

.container div {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```